# Is multiplication by an orthogonal matrix Lebesgue measure preserving?

Tags: linear-algebra, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

I had a very simple question, that I cannot figure out:

Let $A \subseteq \mathbb{R}^d$ for some positive integer $d$. Suppose that $A$ has Lebesgue measure $0$. Let $Q$ be an orthogonal matrix. Then, does the set:
$$Q A := \{Q a: a\in A\}$$ also have Lebesgue measure $0$?
Further, is it true that multiplication by an orthogonal matrix preserves Lebsgue measure?

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: If $M$ is any real $d \times d$ matrix then the set $MA$ is Lebesgue measurable. Also, if $\mu$ is Lebesgue measure then $\mu(MA) = | \det M | \mu(A)$. These facts are usually proved in measure theory textbooks. There is probably an easier proof in the special case where $M$ is orthogonal.

Comment: Thanks a lot! So, for orthogonal matrices $|\mathrm{det}(Q)| = 1$, and hence the result follows.